# Display a Live555 RTSP stream

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, live555

I am developing a RTSP client for desktop (C++). I now understand the operation of the library [live555](http://www.live555.com) and I can receive frames with the example "testRTSPClient". Now I want to display the video on the screen.
How to convert data received to image ?

Comment: Too abstract question... maybe you must decode the received data and then create your image.

Comment: https://github.com/yuvalk/demoLive555withFFMPEG

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a codec to convert from the streamed (compressed/encoded) format to a format that you can draw to screen. I suggest using FFMPEG (libavcodec), there are several examples of how to use FFMPEG to create a media player.